# How to abstract away custom `@types` folders to avoid polluting project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Suppose I have a folder structure like below,

```
project
└── src
    └── components
        │   └── common
        │        └── ui
        │            └────Button
        │            │     ├── index.tsx
        │            │     └── @types
        │            │            └── index.d.ts
        │            └────TextField
        │                  ├── index.tsx
        │                  └── @types
        │                         └── index.d.ts
        └── features
                └── featureA
                         └── components
                                 ├── DataGrid
                                 │     ├── @types
                                 │     │      └── index.d.ts
                                 │     ├── index.tsx
                                 │     ├── DataGridCell
                                 │     │      ├── @types
                                 │     │      │      └── index.d.ts
                                 │     │      └── index.tsx
                    . . . .and so on . . .
```

What's happening here is that every major component has its own `@types` folder. The problem here is that I feel like I'm doing something wrong and I feel like I'm polluting my project tree too much by adding `@types` where I need it.

What is the best way to abstract this all away into some other (perhaps root?) folder, where all of these types will live?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure the behavior of typescript but I think typescript will somehow parse the type in the `@types/index.d.ts` to the global type namespace. For instance,

```
If you accidentally have the same interface name like `Props`

in `Button/@types/index.d.ts`
interface Props {
  type: string
}

in `TextField/@types/index.d.ts`
interface Props {
  value: string
}

the `Props` in the global type namespace will be merged like
{
  type: string
  value: string
}
```

Personally, I just put the component interface type in the corresponding tsx file. It works without big problem so far.

Comment: Yeah, I've had it in the corresponding tsx file as well, but some modules got very bloated, so I decided to move the typings away. Perhaps I should just move them back 

Answer (score 0):

1.In TS, type files, and especially global type files, are used mainly for annotating components that are written in JS - you don't really need to declare types explicitly if you are using TS, annotating the functions of the interfaces you export inline would be enough for TS to pick up the types.

2.You would typically want to store an interface in a separate file because the interface is shared between a lot of different components. In this case it makes sense for the TS file to be somewhere in the root folder.

3.Don't use global type files `.d.ts`. Instead, declare your types in normal `.ts` files, using `export` and `import` to get them where you need them. In this way you would always know from where a given type is coming, no matter where the file is located.